# How can I find self-charging gear?

Tags: heat-signature

The only way I've seen to find self-charging gear in Heat Signature is to hope that a "liberator" character eventually shows up with something. Is there a way normal characters can find self-charging gear? There are various personal missions that are all but impossible without that kind of kit, but I haven't found any in all my travels (and I feel like I'm pretty late-game).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're still rare, but my strategy has been spending *all* my money on "*Overpriced Mystery Crate*" from the Miscellaneous Shop (and the Liberation Mission eventually).

[image: Overpriced Mystery Crate]

I've unlocked a few of those items for sale; but overpriced mystery crate is always there.

An example of all the loot on a character I had when I loaded the game:
[image: Self-charging Inventory]

Basically I just spend all my money on the cases and then sell all the junk and keep anything better than current inventory.